# Why doesn't autoref capitalize?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, autoref

Why does `\autoref` not capitalize my sections?  I think it capitalizes everything else and I have the line `\newcommand{\sectionautoref}{Section}`.

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{fullpage}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
     \usepackage{comment}
    
     \usepackage{caption}
     \usepackage{subcaption}
    
    
     \usepackage[ruled,vlined,algo2e]{algorithm2e}
     \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
     \usepackage{hyperref}
    \usepackage{thm-restate}
      \newcommand{\propositionautorefname}{Proposition}
        \newcommand{\sectionautoref}{Section}
        \def\subsectionautorefname{Section}%
        \newcommand{\remarkautorefname}{Remark}
    
    \begin{document}
    \section{1}\label{sec1}
    
    \section{2}
    \autoref{sec1}
    
    \end{document}`
```

Comment: `\renewcommand{\sectionautorefname}{Section}`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer  That worked, thank you very much  can you explain what is going on here?

Comment: you used the wrong command name.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer  Do proposition and remark also need to be  \renewcommand{\sectionautorefname}{Proposition} and \renewcommand{\sectionautorefname}{Remark}  ?  I don't understand.

Comment: Ulrike meant that instead of `\sectionautorefname`, you only typed `\sectionautoref` in your code.